# Make money out of something

Tags: grammar

What is the correct tense in the following?

> One day, I will be playing the piano and I will be getting money from it.

Is there a better way to express that I would be making money as a pianist?

Comment: 'One day, I will be a professional pianist.' (Nothing to do with the ivory trade.)

Comment: One day, I will be paid to play the piano.

Comment: I would say "... and I will be making money doing it", or something similar.  (That is, if I could carry a tune in a bucket.)

Comment: ...”and getting paid for it” is the phrasing I hear.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is fine, but I would say *earning money* rather than *getting money*.

Comment: I thought that future continuous tense will be + ING is used if something will be in progress in particular time such as “I will be playing the piano between 2 and 3 as I have a piano lesson.” but here is quite indefinite ONE DAY in the future, or is it specific that exactly one day? Then, if the sentence would be without “one day”, and it would be “I will be playing the piano and I will earning money.”, then what tense? still same?           Also make money FROM it is fine? How about OUT OF IT?   Thank you

Comment: Another use of the _ing_ form is habitual: I will be habitually (playing the piano and) earning money. _From_ works better than _out of_ for me.

Comment: A busker might talk of "getting money".